# How to 'extract' css elements from a div (that is forming a grid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to build a grid to run directly with hardware connected to a raspberry pi. On the client side, I am trying to have a button that saves the current "frame" of the grid. I'd like for this button to just gather the CSS color values (in hexadecimal form) and form an array with them, but everything I have tried hasn't worked as of yet.

I am aware of the 'style' and 'computedStyles' methods in javascript, and these may be part of the key to the question, but I'm not sure. My hunch is that the issue lies within state.

```
<div id="palette">
      <div
        class="pen"
        style="background-color: #ffffff;"
        onclick="setPenColor('#ffffff')"
      ></div>


<--- Yadayada more 'pens' -->
<div id="art">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="pixel" onclick="setPixelColor(this)"></div>
        <div class="pixel" onclick="setPixelColor(this)"></div>
        <div class="pixel" onclick="setPixelColor(this)"></div>
        <div class="pixel" onclick="setPixelColor(this)"></div>

    <--- Javascript -->

var penColor = 'black';

function setPenColor(pen) {
  penColor = pen;
}

function setPixelColor(pixel) {
  pixel.style.backgroundColor = penColor;
}

var element = document.getElementById('pixel');
var out = '';
var elementStyle = element.style;
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);

for (prop in elementStyle) {
  if (elementStyle.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    out +=
      '  ' +
      prop +
      " = '" +
      elementStyle[prop] +
      "' > '" +
      computedStyle[prop] +
      "'\n";
  }
}
console.log(out);

<-- CSS -->
#art {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.pixel {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: white;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.pen {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

My current output just gives me an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at grid.js:24
```

Like I said, I'd like to form an array of the hexadecimal values, but accessing them properly has become my first priority now.

Thanks much for any help! :)

Comment: Telling you that `element` is null which  means that `id` doesn't exist when you run the code. You have numerous `class=pixel` but no `id=pixel`

Comment: You are trying to get an ID but you need to get the class. use getElementsByClassName instead.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error